# How should I fix ChunkedEncodingError?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

I am getting this error
**ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(14 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(14 bytes read))**
I am making a POST request from the "requests" library (3rd party) in Google App Engine using python.

```
url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
        body = {
            "data": {
                "title": "data:mytitle",
                "body": "data:mybody",
                "url": "data:myurl"
            },
            "notification": {
                "title": "noti:My web app name",
                "body": "noti:message",
                "content_available": "noti:true"
            },
            "message": "test",
            "registration_ids": ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
        }
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Authorization": "key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

        logging.error(json.dumps(body))
        requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with Google App Engine is that one cannot alone work with "requests", we need to also use "requests-toolbelt" along with it. 
Step 1: add requests-toolbelt to appDIR/lib
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library

Step 2: Inside main.py add

```
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
```

This will fix the problem.

Comment: This is correct.  The documentation for [Issuing HTTP(S) Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request) explains that including **requests--toolbelt** ensures that the **requests** library uses **URL Fetch** instead of its default of sockets.

Comment: This works ! I was trying to read sheet using gspread and was facing ChunkedEncodingError issue. Now resolved ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue and I used [PyFCM](https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM). and everything worked. If you are willing to use it just make sure you install version 1.2.8 or later. Any version below that will result in the same issue you're having